# If Six Is Easy, Is Ten So Hard?

Tags: riddle, rhyme, steganography

> No artist, I, in tones and hues.
>   No songs, no notes, no sounds I use.
>   No social set, no friends for me.
>   You see me not? Scan carefully
>   From first to last on every row.
>   From onset to the end I show.

The answer is a single English word. The riddle tag is debatable. The answer, when you find it, will be clear and unambiguous.

Comment: Is it related to computers?

Comment: No, not computer related.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I think the answer is:

> stone.

How is it hidden?

> There are anagrams of stone in every line except the fourth and fifth: (tones), (notes), (set, no), (onset). An anagram of stone also appears in the title: (Ten So).
>
>  In addition, stone is hidden forwards in the fifth line (la**st on e**very) and backwards on the fourth line (m**e not? S**can).

Finally,

> the poem fits the answer, even if it doesn't unambiguously define it. The first three lines are quite clear. The "Scan carefully" could be interpreted as leaving no stone unturned: the anagrams can be "turned" to get "stone".

Comment: English is really enough to make one despair. "Scan" is its own antonym. It can mean either "inspect carefully" or "skim hastily".

Comment: In "scan carefully" it's clear which one is meant, but I thought that scanning was purely visual, whereas leaving no stone unturned seems to involve opening or dismantling objects in order to look inside.

Comment: Ah. Fair enough.

Comment: The "single word answer" to the only *question* is probably *yes*. "Is ***** hard?" would usually be answered that way, even though there are some that wouldn't usually be called hard.

Comment: @SetBigO: I think hard is just another hint towards the actual answer, stone. Since there is no real question (except the cryptic title and "You see me not?"), I took the question to be in implied "What am I?"

Comment: There's also one in the title :O

Comment: @QBrute: Yes, but I have written that in my answer, haven't I?

Comment: @MOehm oops yes. I should read more carefully >_>

Answer (score 5):

Oh it's

> "." , the period/ full stop ?

No songs, no notes, no sounds I use.

> it's silent

From first to last on every row.

> because It Is on every row , and because

From onset to the end I show.

You see me not? Scan carefully

> it's under the "?"

Comment: Good. +1 You can add the title as well _"If Six Is Easy, Is Ten So Hard?"_ "." over i is easy and "." over ? is a little harder.

Answer (score 4):

Partial Working -

> With 6 I thought it was 6 times "No" was repeated. Also, *"From first to last on every row."* I guess the letter which are present in each line which gives **"onset"** which are present on every line which when anagram gives english words like "notes", "stone" and very importantly **"Steno"** who is a shorthand typist.

So, it could be

> **Steno**

Comment: That's a good observation, but I think you picked the wrong word. `:)`

Comment: Yeah. Unfortunately :)

Answer (score 2):

I am really horrible at steganography But here is what I found out so far.

> There are 10 capital letters in the text. 10 in total, and 6 before the "?" which could be a clue related with the title.(or just pure coincidence.)
>  The riddle tag was explained as being debatable which means it's really just the result of steganography. But since the tag was still added it means that among the riddle, there is probably a clue to how to solve the steganography problem. Which makes me think that the last 2 rows are a clue as to how we must do something with the beginning and end of each lines to find the solution.
>  I also noticed that a dot was omitted after "Scan carefully" which is probably an important detail.(or a typo)

Answer (score 2):

Is the answer

> IAMBIC?

No artist, I, in tones and hues.
No songs, no notes, no sounds I use.

> Poems use none of these things.

You see me not? Scan carefully

> "Scan" is used to refer to how a poem's lines read

From first to last on every row.
From onset to the end I show.

> The entire line is covered by metrical feet.